# Обработать нажатие клавиши по таймеру

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular

Пытаюсь реализовать живой поиск на Angular.

Мой HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBox"
  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search"
  [(ngModel)]="searchNoteValue"
  (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"
/>
```

TypeScript:

```
onSearchChange(searchValue: string): void {
    timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
        this.searchNotes();
    });
}
```

В данной реализации функция вызывается по кол-ву нажатых клавиш. 
Пример ввожу в инпут "АВС", проходит секунда -> отправляется 3 запроса с "АВС". Как сделать так, чтобы функция вызывалась один раз?

Comment: Вам нужен не timer, а debounce.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не совсем понимаю как он работает, забагованный какой-то

Comment: что бы понимать, надо получать знания. Знания можно получить методом тыка, как вы пытаетесь. Иногда, на простых вещах, это работает. Но лучше читать документацию. Читайте доки по `debounce` и вы все поймете, я верю в вас!

Comment: Данил, ответ @SergeyRogachev является правильным, пометь его пожалуйста галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это реализация через реактивные формы:

```
this.searchFormGroup.controls['search'].valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(200), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
  .subscribe((val) => {
    /* реализация вашего метода */
  });
```

Реализация через шаблон:

```
/** В теле компоненты */
public searchEventEmitter: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
    /*
     * Подписываемся на события эмиттера. Как только пройдет 
     * 200 милисекунд с последнего события выполниться код в subscribe 
     */
    this.searchEventEmitter
        .pipe(debounceTime(200), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe((val) => {
            /* реализация вашего метода */
        });
}

onSearchChange(searchValue: string): void {
   /** При каждом изменении кидаем событие*/
   searchEventEmitter.next(searchValue);
}
```

Comment: `takeUntil` должен быть после `debounceTime`, иначе он комплитает `valueChanges` обзервер, при этом `debounceTime` обзевер остается активным вместе с асинхронным планировщиком.

Comment: @overthesanity, а пруфы есть на этот счёт? Почитать, ознакомиться?

Comment: Я только это нашёл: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Comment: Какие пруфы? Это очевидные вещи для тех, кто знает rxjs, что-то из оперы "докажите, что нужно вообще отписываться".

Comment: @overthesanity, я не к тому, что не доверяю, а к тому, что бы с этим ознакомиться подробнее.

Comment: у Николаса в rxjs-tslint-rules есть [список операторов, которые могут идти после takeUntil](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/blob/master/source/rules/rxjsNoUnsafeTakeuntilRule.ts#L46). бОльшая часть из них для мультикастинга, а остальные утилитные. По самому rx'у статей не так уж много, а ты спрашиваешь про takeUntil и утечки.... =))

Comment: @overthesanity, благодарю!